# javascript chart library or php chart library

Tags: charts

Can anyone recommend a javascript or php chart library that allow me to scroll and zoom in/zoom out the chart like the google stock chart? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Flot is a javascript library with some capabilities like this. Here is an example (not exactly what you're looking for, but similar): http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/zooming.html

Here is flot: http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Comment: I've used flot for a while and love it. Great defaults plus a very good architecture that makes it easy to customize.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use google interactive charts? There looks like there are some tools for effects like zoom, etc.

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/interactive_charts.html